# How can I echo out content of if statement

Tags: php, checkbox

i have 5 of these:

```
if(isset($_POST['checkbox'])) {
   $name = "Alex";
}
```

How can I echo the name of every selected checkbox outside of the if statement?

Comment: Can you be a little more descriptive in what you want to achieve?  How many are there?  Do you mean the `$name` variable that you set?

Comment: You mean that you have 5 separate if statements, right?

Comment: Well once a form is submitted, I want to display the name variable of all the checkboxes checked.

Comment: yes @theomessin

Comment: @AbraCadaver yes I have 5 different if statements all with different names, once the form is submitted with the checkboxes, those checkboxes that were checked I want to display the name that i set as $name in the if statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your example, build an array of `$name`:

```
if(isset($_POST['checkbox'])) {
   $name[] = "Alex";
}
if(isset($_POST['checkbox1'])) {
   $name[] = "Bob";
}
```

Then either:

```
echo implode(', ', $name);
```

Or:

```
foreach($name as $value) {
    echo $value;
}
```

But actually I'm wondering why not just set the values in the form inputs (use an array):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="Alex">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="Bob">
```

Then:

```
foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $value) {
    echo $value;
}
```

Comment: Alright, now lets say I have $type[] = 'Name:' as well in the if statement, how can I implode both arrays? next to teacher like Name: Alex